# YouTube multiple audio tracks

Tags: video, streaming, youtube

I have a problem. I want to do YouTube videos with two voice-overs. And i know that it is possible because Assassin's Creed: Valhala's first trailer has it. But i can't find any way how to do it. Any suggestions?

Situation:
-I tried to add multiple songs in the youtube studio if this will work, it didn't work.
-I tried to upload video that had 3 audio tracks: 1. video audio,2. song, 3. song. On pc i could switch it. But on youtube it didn't worked. It didn't showed me the option of choosing the audio track. And it played the first audiotrack

Comment: We need more information: what is your problem - meaning what exactly does not work? Have you tried to upload a video with multiple audio tracks and it didn't work? Was there any error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens when I upload a multi-audio video to YouTube?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/16895/what-happens-when-i-upload-a-multi-audio-video-to-youtube)

Comment: Please note that the question @Gyan has linked may have obsolete answers, since YouTube started to support multiple audio tracks in autumn 2020 (whether this applies to all users or only to a selected group I don't know). So those answers may need to be updated.

Comment: I've searched myself a bit but haven't found out anything in the documentation or elsewhere about the new feature so far. I think what you can do is to use YouTube's feedback system to send a bug report and hope they'll fix it or clarify whether multi-track audio is available for all users or not. If you find out anything new, add an answer to the question that Gyan has linked.